# how can integrate node.js on Asp project?

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, asp.net-core, rsa

I have an old asp project.

I need to create an implement a satispay method payment.

This require a code for signature of rsa-sha256 of header for auth.

I tried several way to do this with c# but with no result.

I tried so to do it with node.js file that has a crypto library, and worked very well.

but now how can i use this script on my asp page?

this is my script:

```
'use strict';
var http = require('http');
var port = process.env.port || 8080;
const crypto = require('crypto')
const body = `{
  "flow": "MATCH_CODE",
  "amount_unit": 100,
  "currency": "EUR"
}`
const privateKey = 'my key'
const publicKey = "my key";

const keyId = "my key";

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    const digest = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(body).digest('base64')
    var d = new Date()
    const string = `(request-target): post /wally-services/protocol/tests/signature
    host: staging.authservices.satispay.com
    date: ${d.toUTCString()}
    digest: SHA-256=${digest}`
    const signature = crypto.createSign('RSA-SHA256').update(string).sign(privateKey, 'base64')

    const authorizationHeader = `Signature keyId="${keyId}", algorithm="rsa-sha256", headers="(request-target) host date digest", signature="${signature}"`

    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text-plain' })
    res.end(string);


}).listen(port)
```

that worked but i can't use it on my project

**EDIT:**

other solution that could really help me is how use require('crypto') and his function on a basic js file without node

Comment: It should be perfectly possible to create such a hash using C#. What exactly did you try? What went wrong. It ought to be simpler and more reliable to get that right than to try and integrate a separate server-side environment into your existing one.

Comment: P.S. However, when you say "old asp project"...how old exactly? What version of .NET does it run on? You've tagged the question with asp.net-core which is only 3 years old.

Comment: Hi, my mistake is not an asp,net with c# is old because it's have only asp page with code on them. My problem is that i need to do some stuff with crypto library of node.js, and i need that now, i've created the script but in another project with node js, i absolutly need to use that node js code on asp page

Comment: Do you mean ASP Classic? Script files with .asp extension? If so then yes it would be harder to do the encryption. What you could do is run the nodeJS as a separate webservice. Then you would make a HTTP request to it from the asp code, so that the nodeJS service would generate the hash value and return it in the response.

Comment: Yes is asp Classic, but for paypal integration i created a folder using recent asp.net and calling with ajax call, but i can't do it the same cause c# crypto lib is so different, but if you have a way to do it  i will be gratefull

Comment: Why? .net has RSA encryption ability. Did you Google any examples? I'm not an expert with that specifically but I can't really see why it wouldn't work, unless the .net version is old too

Comment: it has but work differently, and not has function for signHash in rsa-sha256 for example, i tried a lot but with bad result

Comment: Ok. Well your options are a) make it work in c# (maybe someone more expert with encryption will see this and be able to help), or b) use my idea above to run nodeJS as a webservice and then make calls to it, like you are doing with the asp.net already